# Работа с файлами в PHP

Tags: php, файлы, книги

Кто подскажет статьи и руководства для изучения работы по считыванию/изменению данных с помощью PHP?

Я понял как работать с текстовыми файлами **.txt*. Теперь меня интересует управления другими форматами.

Например. Шаблон создания всех типов файлов понятен

```
fopen('1.rar','w+');
```

А теперь как запихивать в архивчик файлы или как получить все его содержимое,удалить выбранные файлы? Аналогично архивам хочется узнать и про другие форматы xsl и др..

Спасибо.

Comment: [Функции для работы с файловой системой](http://php.su/functions/?page=cat_filesystem)

Comment: Для каждого формата файлов есть свои расширения/классы php. А так - системе все равно, что открывать: текстовый файл или файл видео.

Comment: Нашел про создание архивов http://www.koz1024.net/php/ziparchive.html

Comment: Ты пытаешься объединить слишком разные вещи в одном. Нужно искать материалы под конкретную задачу, а такого обобщения, как ты хочешь, вероятно не будет нигде.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[php.net - zip](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.zip.php)
[php.net - rar](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.rar.php)